# Mantaflow Fire Sim Apply And Move Blend

Tags: blend-files, mantaflow

I have created a Manataflow Fire sim and have identified the frame I want from the sim. I need to take this object and import it into a different blend to incorporate into an animation.

The issue I'm struggling with is how to Apply this modifier. Or at least I think that's what I'm looking to do. I haven't done this for a while and with the older style sims you could convert things to mesh and then treat it like any other mesh object.

Mantaflow doesn't seem to want to play like that and I'm struggling to find much info on how to achieve this.

How would I go about isolating this single frames sim data and applying it as a mesh? Or am I thinking too old school in relation to Mantaflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fire simulation is not a mesh, it is a volume information holding certain data like density, temperature, flame etc.

So if you now bake a simulation (choose *Format Volumes* > *OpenVDB* under the domain's *Cache* settings) you can find different folders in the specified path, one is called "data". There all the fluid data is stored. **One thing to note:** if you want to keep the *OpenVDB* data file to import it to other blend files I would recommend to move or duplicate it (or the complete bake) in another location other than the designated cache path, otherwise you might accidentally free the bake in the domain and delete all files which you might have wanted to use later.

[image: simulation data folders]

To import a single frame of these, you can use the *Add* menu in the *3D Viewport* by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose *Volume* > *Import OpenVDB*.

[image: import openvdb file]

In the *Import* dialogue window navigate to the folder where the data is stored. The files are numbered, so if you want to import the data from e.g. frame 15, choose the file which is called "fluid_data_0015.vdb" and import it.

[image: select file to import]

Now you have a volume object in the scene. If you go to the *Object Data Properties* tab you can see the data *Grids* stored in the file and which you can access in the material shader either through the *Volume Info* node or an *Attribute* node.

[image: volume grids]

By the way, below the file name there is also a checkbox *Sequence*. If you enable it, you can enter the number of *Frames*, on which (scene) frame to *Start* the animation and the *Offset* is how many frames of the sequence you want to skip. Note that if you enable the sequence it does not matter if you opened file 0015 or 0001, it will always take the complete sequence into account and base frames, start and offset on that. This way you can import a full or partial fire simulation into a scene without the need to keep a domain, flow object etc.

[image: enable sequence]

Last but not least you can give this object a material like a *Smoke Domain* and render it as smoke and fire. The only I found is that somehow the same material looks different on a smoke domain than on a volume object. But with a little tweaking you can get basically the same look as with the simulation.

[image: render smoke and fire]

Comment: Wow, so this process seems awkward. Many thanks for the detailed write-up. The trouble I now have is that I had to use Uni Cache to get my original bake to complete as OpenVDB kept crashing ... even using Zip compression. Hmm ...

Comment: @Jammer Yeah right, I remember. That's a bummer because _Import OpenVDB_ is as far as I know the only way to get smoke simulation data into Blender.

Comment: Think I'm going to have to regroup and re-strategise. If I'm in a situation where I have to repeat all my baking anyway. I might just re-bake things in the target blend file and be done with it. Sims are still so damn awkward to work with eh.

Comment: One question that leads on from this is the noise data. Is that file also imported along with the related `fluid_data_xxx` file?

Comment: @Jammer No, it is not. You could import the noise data separately, but then you have to give it a different material, since the normal data file contains the grids `density` and `flame` but in the noise file they are called `density_noise` and `flame_noise`

Comment: Hmm. It gets more awkward! You know what. I'm just going to render out an image ... lol. I've always found sims awkward to work with and it doesn't seem to be getting any easier to work with over time. Complex things eh.

Comment: Thanks for all your time. Much appreciated.

Comment: LOL I can't even get an image out. Shows in the render view but saving to an image excludes the fire and compositing. I'm cursed.